# MongoDB document merge without a-priori knowledge of fields

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I would like to merge several documents. Most of the fields have the same values but there might be one or two fields that have different values. These fields are unknown beforehand. Ideally I would like to merge all the documents keeping the fields that are the same as is but creating an array of values only for those fields that have some variation.

For my first approach I grouped by a common field to my documents and kept the first document, this however discards some information that varies in other fields.

```py
     group_documents = {
         "$group": {
           "_id": "$0020000E.Value",
           "doc": {
             "$first": "$$ROOT"
           }
         }
     }
   

     merge_documents = {
         "$replaceRoot": {
           "newRoot": "$doc"
         }
     }

     write_collection = { "$out": { "db": "database", "coll": "records_nd" } }

    objects = coll.aggregate(pipeline)
```

IF the fields that have different values where known I would have done something like this,

[merge_sol1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273344/how-to-merge-document-in-mongodb-based-on-an-id)
or
[merge_sol2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678233/mongodb-merging-documents-in-php)
or
[merge_sol3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69870545/mongodb-filter-and-merge-document-with-common-field)

The third solution is actually very close to my desired output and I could tweak it a bit. But these answers assume a-priori knowledge of the fields to be merged.

Comment: Maybe `$mergeObjects` would help here?

Comment: I don't think in this case since it states in the documentation that "$mergeObjects overwrites the field values as it merges the documents. If documents to merge include the same field name, the field, in the resulting document, has the value from the last document merged for the field." In this case I need to keep all values and not just the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first convert `$$ROOT` to array of k-v tuples by `$objectToArray`. Then, `$group` all fields by `$addToSet` to put all distinct values into an array first. Then, check the size of the result array and conditionally pick the first item if the array size is 1 (i.e. the value is the same for every documents in the field); Otherwise, keep the result array. Finally, revert back to original document form by `$arrayToObject`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$key",
      arr: {
        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$arr"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "arr.k": {
        $nin: [
          "key",
          "_id"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        id: "$_id",
        k: "$arr.k"
      },
      v: {
        "$addToSet": "$arr.v"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$_id.id",
      arr: [
        {
          k: "$_id.k",
          v: {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $gt: [
                  {
                    $size: "$v"
                  },
                  1
                ]
              },
              "then": "$v",
              "else": {
                $first: "$v"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      doc: {
        "$arrayToObject": "$arr"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          {
            _id: "$_id"
          },
          "$doc"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zLGogYQcfXA)

Comment: Hi ray thanks for your answer, this is exactly what I'm hoping to achieve. In this case however you known fields a and b a-priori and you add them to the set. Is there maybe a way to iterate this solution through every field given a document where the schema is not known?

Comment: @Axe_83 updated the answer to have more wrangling through `$objectToArray` and `$arrayToObject`

Comment: Just finished testing it with some case data. It worked like a charm. Thank you very much for the all help!